# How to make graphons pictures?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I came across this amazing lecture notes https://yufeizhao.com/gtacbook/gtacbook.pdf, and I wanted to create examples of graph limits. Does anyone know which package/software to use for creating figures like these?

[image]

Any help is appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You have tagged `tikz-pgf` which is the coding style that can be used to create those images. You can go through the `tikz` manual for guidance or look at these [`tikz` examples](https://texample.net/tikz/examples/all/) that have code and see if any fit what you are looking for

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With loops (and test for the second figure):

```latex
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=0.8pt]
    \foreach \i in {0,...,6}{
    \foreach \j in {\i,...,6}{
    \draw (\i,0) -- (\j,5);
    }
    \draw[fill=white] (\i,5) circle [radius=2mm];
    \draw[fill=lightgray] (\i,0) circle [radius=2mm];
    }
    
    \foreach \i in {0,...,14}{
    \draw (7.5+\i/2,-1) -- (7.5+\i/2,6);
    \draw (7.5,\i/2-1) -- (14.5,\i/2-1);
    \ifnum \i<7
    \filldraw (7.5+\i/2,-1) rectangle (8+\i/2,2.5-\i/2);
    \filldraw (14.5-\i/2,6) rectangle (14-\i/2,2.5+\i/2);
    \fi 
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image]